# Close a question by bug fix or update

Tags: discussion, support, questions, vote-to-close

How should you handle a question that is answered by or is no longer applicable because of a bug fix or update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Post an answer describing the bug fix and/or applicable update(s). Be specific about what the bug was, and in which versions the fix can be found. Ideally, include a supplemental link to the relevant issue tracker.

If you have technical details about what caused the bug and/or how it was fixed, or even what kind of spill-over effects the fix might have, then that would make for an *awesome* answer (but obviously isn't *necessary*).

Once an answer has been posted, it can be accepted, which will mark the question as "answered". It does not matter who posts the answer. It can either be the person who asked the question answering their own question, or someone else answering it. Either way, it can be accepted.

Comment: Also, don't *only* post a link to the bug tracker.

Comment: Upvoted answers also mark a question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Something to keep in mind is that questions don't automatically adjust with  time and development; a question was asked about a specific version or combination of versions which may have a bug or may be lacking specific features which make life easier. New versions come out and bugs are fixed and features are retired in favour of better ones, which people should use if they have access to it.

*But the old version does not automatically disappear from systems where it is installed and used!*

The fact that the bug is ultimately fixed in a subsequent version does not make the question obsolete in the slightest as the question does not automatically move its target to the updated version; people may still be using the bugged version and so the question is still relevant and potentially can stay that way for many years to come depending on how persistent older versions are. Especially in platforms which do not maintain backwards compatibility very well or at all this can be a realistic scenario as upgrade paths become expensive and risky.

An answer stating "This was bug X, it was fixed in version Y" will thus have a target audience, we should not assume they've become irrelevant just because you should be using a newer version; our local situations and possibilities do not reflect the entire world. Of course it is important to have a key piece of information: the specific version the question was targeting. That information is often not volunteered when the question is asked but it is vital to have to make the question resistant to aging away.