# How to handle answers which point to a pull request?

Tags: discussion, answers

One of the questions that I have come across claims that the particular software is not working as expected and they are unable to debug the root cause of it. The question has adequate info to replicate it.

Question: [Aiflow skipping task on ONE_SUCCESS trigger rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64603004/6629148)

The answer links to a a pull request (PR). The answerer has mentioned that they too are facing the same issue and have raised a pull request in the Github repo of the software in question.

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67311940/6629148

This is not exactly an answer but the PR does contain valuable info which could build up to an answer.

How to handle such an answer? Should we alert the answerer to provide more info about their fix?

Or should we let them know that this doesn't meet the criteria for an answer directly and should rather be mentioned in a comment to the question?

Comment: Gotta love edge cases. Strictly speaking, it is an answer. "It's a bug and there's a PR to fix it" -- that qualifies.

Comment: I disagree, @Zoe , the answer *isn't* an answer. It's just a link showing that the problem *might* be solved in a future release (and that that contribution is by the answerer). It doesn't discuss, in the answer, what the cause is nor how to fix it in the answer (the OP might be able to compile their own version for example, if they *really* wanted), nor offer any interim work around. That PR *could* be sitting there for months or years depending on the repository owner; that wouldn't be helpful to the question asker. To me, the answer should be a comment in its current state.

Comment: @Larnu "It's a bug" is still, within [our definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), an answer. It's not a good answer, I'll give you that, but a bad answer is still an answer.

Comment: @Zoe: can you be a little more specific in how that overmeta post says it's an answer? That page doesn't mention the word "bug" anywhere, and the whole apple/orange thing is waaaaaaaaaaay too open to intepretation.

Comment: "Or let them know that this doesn't meet the criteria for an answer directly and should rather be mentioned as a comment in question?" This advice is only useful to users who have the privilege to comment on other people's posts. The author of the answer in question doesn't (50 reputation needed).

Comment: @Cerbrus "Yes, they're both very short, and yes, they contain links. But strip the markup, and you still get at least a little bit of useful information." - it being a bug is useful information, and there being a pending patch is also useful information. Also: "Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined."

Comment: [Your definition of _"useful"_ differs from mine](https://xkcd.com/979/). The answer's author has left a lot of information out of the answer, and if you strip all formatting, all you know is that, _someone, somewhere_ has an answer to your question.

Comment: Useful information <> an answer @Zoe . If I posted an answer fixing a user's code from injection attacks, but didn't answer the question they asked it would be useful, most certainly, but it's not an answer to the question. Though a different train of thought, usefulness does not make an answer an *actual* answer. They *can* go hand in hand, but one does not dictate the other.

Comment: Let's not confuse the "NAA" flag with whether or not the answer answers the question, by the way. I don't think anyone here is suggesting that it should be flagged as "NAA".

Comment: If I'm facing the same issue, I'd rather see an answer telling me that it is a bug in the software than no answer at all. It's probably not the answer I hoped for, but at least I can stop digging and start working around it.

Comment: We already [have guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358441) on what to do if an issue is caused by a bug: *"Be specific about what the bug was, and in which versions the fix can be found."* - Notably, don't just post a link to an associated PR

Comment: @Ivar what if it wasn't a bug at all and just a misunderstanding from the answerer?

Comment: @Braiam That's a risk you have with every answer. Or at least those with little traffic. Of course you should never fully rely on single answer that you can't verify, but if that is the only piece of information you can find, I'd still rather have that, than no information at all. (Either way I end up with no real/quick solution to my problem, so not too much harm done there.) If in time someone comes by who can debunk it, then I'd encourage them to add a different answer. If that doesn't happen, it might actually truly be a bug.

Comment: @Ivar if you could find the answer, you could also find the bug report/pull request, isn't it? The information would still be there, just not on SE. Also, I prefer reducing risks whenever I can, and this is a unnecessary one. If I find the bug report I could potentially subscribe myself or at least verify that it's the same issue, since bug report should contain the method to reproduce the bug... right?

Comment: @Braiam If both the SO post and the PR are equally well written and indexed, then yes, you have a valid point regarding that this will be the only piece of information you will be able to find. But it still wouldn't hurt to also have this information on SO. Especially with a link to the PR (albeit supplementary). It still adds value to our repository of Q&A's IMO.

Answer (score 9):

Ask the answerer to summarize the content of the pull request (what changes it makes, etc), or to elaborate why they think it is an issue that needs fixing. If the pull request doesn't add anything to the Q&A, there's not much more that needs to be done besides update the answer if/when a fix is shipped by the vendor. The answer, while short and to the point, is neither NAA nor a link-only answer.

Answer (score 5):

The link to a PR is a red-herring. It's neither here nor there. On its own, it's simply a link to an external resource.

If the answer was:

> [Here](https://example.com) is a PR that fixes this issue.

It would certainly be NAA, as with any other link-only answer.

In this case, what we should decide is that if:

> I believe it is an underlying issue with airflow

... qualifies as "NAA" or not.

Strictly speaking, I believe it is **not** flag worthy, although I wouldn't be surprised (or disappointed) if a mod honoured such a flag.

Better to be safe: it's just a poor answer: vote, and comment if you will.